# ANDROID - create a new Oval class with every finger-moved x and y coodrinates

Tags: java, android, motionevent

I want to do this:

1. - when I touch the screen, I want to create a new Oval to the touched x,y coordinates
2. - when I am dragging my finger on the screen, I want to create new Ovals to every x,y coordinates where my finger was during the dragging.
3. - when I touch and I am holding my finger on the screen (longpressing), I want to delete every Ovals I created

I can do the first step, but I don't know how to do the 2. and 3.

Here is my code I tried:

```
public class BouncingBallView extends View implements OnGestureListener{

private List<Oval> ovals = new ArrayList<Oval>();
private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

public BouncingBallView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for(Oval o: ovals) { //prints every oval
        o.graph(canvas);
    } 
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //1. this works:
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    Oval oval = new Oval(x, y, this);
    ovals.add(oval);
    invalidate();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float x,
        float y) {
    //2. this doesn't work:
    Oval oval = new Oval(x, y, this);
    ovals.add(oval);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    //3. this doesn't work:
    ovals.clear();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float x,
        float y) {
    //2. this doesn't work:
    Oval oval = new Oval(x, y, this);
    ovals.add(oval);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

You can see, I don't use the "gestureScanner" parameter, maybe I should, but I don't know where and how!

Please Help me! Thx!